# How to create an ajax request within google scripts with '$' variable error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I'd like to use the ajax() method to perform an AJAX Request. I've tried to create the below functions within scripts.google.com, but I get the following error:

```
function AjaxCall() {
var arr = { City: 'Moscow', Age: 25 };


      $.ajax({
    url: 'https://worker-aws-us-east-1.iron.io/2/projects/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});

}
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (line 5, file "Code")
```

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that jquery has been included before this method is being executed?

Comment: that's a great question - how would you go about including jquery. I've tried to add <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> before the method is executed and have tried to add it via Resources > Libraries with no luck. It seems like I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that jquery isn't sourced in your HTML. Keep in mind that jquery is a client side, javascript library -- so the browser needs to load the jquery javascript file. In other words, a valid reference needs to be in the HTML that is returned to the client browser.

Your comment indicated that you tried:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Try updating that to:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't include the "http://" (or "https://" or "//") in the front of the URL, the browser thinks it's a relative path and will try to load that from the current directory (and that probably isn't what you were trying to do). So, if the page that you were viewing was

```
http://www.examplesite.com/example.html
```

Then, the script tag you showed in your comment would try to load jquery from

```
http://www.examplesite.com/code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
```

This is likely returning a 404 error -- check your javascript console to see if it's receiving an error when trying to load the jquery script.

Also, in most cases, it's recommended that you put the script tag at the bottom (right before the closing body tag). This keeps the page rendering from being blocked as the browser download the js file. This is not likely causing the problems you were originally seeing -- just thought I'd mention it since your comment potentially indicated that you were loading it right before the ajax call.